# How to calculate audio dynamic range?

Tags: audio, wav

In Wiki "dynamic range" is defined as "the ratio of the amplitude of the loudest possible undistorted sine wave to the root mean square (rms) noise amplitude", but I'm not clear about how should I use these operands.

I have read in an uncompressed .wav file. It uses 16 bits per sample, and I've converted these bytes to integers (may range from -32768 to 32767). The largest int is 31692 and the smallest -32764. So what should I do next? I saw the formula "20 * log (high / low)" and it doesn't seem to work directly. Could you please show me the calculation steps? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to test the dynamic range of your audio file using Wikipedia's definition. That is for calculating stuff like the signal to noise ratio (e.g., testing microphones, speakers, etc.), and requires a background in signal processing to understand. Are you sure you're looking for the dynamic range of the audio file and not something else?

Comment: @Anthony Thanks. It's one of my project questions. It reads in a wav file and displays its dynamic range. It says that "the dynamic range is defined as the ratio between the highest power against the lowest power(non-zero) in the stream, measured in decibel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. Actually the formula "20 * log (high / low)" works. "high" should be abs(-32764) = 32764, and low should be the value most near 0 but not 0, which is 1 in my file. So the dynamic range is 20 * log10(32764 / 1) = 90 dB.